# Only parse through the interquartile of a dataset

Tags: c#

Assume I have a `DataTable` named `a` like the one below:

```
|DateTimeSec|value|
|-----------|-----|
|14569980000|8    |
|14570050000|54   |
|14570900000|928  |
|14571250000|67   |
|14571260000|124  |
|14572230000|32   |
|14573980000|211  |
|14574120000|202  |
|-----------|-----|
```

What I want to do is somehow only alter, for example add 10, to only the values in the interquartile range based on the `value` column above. This would result in only 54, 67, 124, and 202 being altered. I want to do this while keeping it ordered by `DateTimeSec`.

I was thinking of having something like this:

First, I'd grab the DataTable from my database and sort it by `value`, then:

```
//grab the interquartile range
var sorted = a.AsEnumerable().Skip((int) (a.Rows.Count * 0.25)).Take((int) (a.Rows.Count * 0.50)).CopyToDataTable();
foreach (DataRow row in sorted) 
{
    row.ItemArray[1] += 10;
}
```

My problem is then what do I do with this interquartile DataTable that I have? Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: More elegant?  Yes.  Sort the table.  Then find the 25th and 75th percentile.  Your interquartile range is > 0.25 and < 0.75.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Yes.  The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) has formulas to help you calculate percentiles.

**Use this function to calculate a value at a given percentile:**

```
private static double GetValueAtPercentile(double[] sequence, double percentile)
{
    if (percentile > 1)
        percentile = percentile * 0.01;

    if (Math.Abs(percentile) > 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("cannot do calculate greater than 1 perc");

    Array.Sort(sequence);
    var N = sequence.Length;
    var n = (N - 1) * percentile + 1;

    if (n == 1d) return sequence[0];
    else if (n == N) return sequence[N - 1];
    else
    {
        var k = (int)n;
        var d = n - k;
        return sequence[k - 1] + d * (sequence[k] - sequence[k - 1]);
    }
}
```

**Now use it in your table:**

```
var sequence = table.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<double>("value"));
var firstQuartile = GetValueAtPercentile(sequence.ToArray(), 25);
var thirdQuartile = GetValueAtPercentile(sequence.ToArray(), 75);

foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    var rowValue = row.Field<double>("value");
    if(rowValue >= firstQuartile && rowValue <= thirdQuartile)
    {
        // Do things
    }
}
```